# News de duplication dataset

Tags: dataset, clustering

I am looking for a news dataset with semantically duplicate news articles tagged.
Basically all the news articles which talk about the same story should be grouped. The stories can be worded differently but at a high level talk about the same event. Something like what google news does. Are there tagged news datasets for this ?

Comment: see this question - https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63813/datasets-for-topic-modeling . Generally you are looking for 'topic modeling'.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lot of articles from multiple news sources and languages discussing the same trending event in this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/global-news-week).

However, it provides no tags for semantically duplicate articles. That is something you have to implement yourself. Check the page of the [source](https://eventregistry.org/) mentioned in the dataset, they provide some event correlation features.